# R Margins: Incorrect number of dimensions

Tags: r

I want to calculate the margins for an independent variable at the values of another independent variable. All variables (including the dependent variable) are binary.

```
model1 <- glm(data = TrialDF, formula = dep ~ indep1*indep2, family=binomial)
margins::margins(model1, data = TrialDF, variables = "indep1",
  at = list("indep2" =c(0,1)))
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Error in dat[, not_numeric, drop = FALSE] : 
  incorrect number of dimensions
```

I also tried variations of this command by using factor variables or list("indep2" = 0:1), but I always get the same error messages. What does that mean?

The data is:

```
TrialDF <-structure(list(dep = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), indep1 = c(1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), indep2 = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1
)), row.names = c(NA, -240L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is related to the problem described in https://github.com/leeper/prediction/pull/34. You can get past it by coercing the data to a data frame with `data=data.frame(TrialDF)`:

```
> margins(model1, data=data.frame(TrialDF), variables="indep1", at=list("indep2"=c(0,1)))
Average marginal effects at specified values
glm(formula = dep ~ indep1 * indep2, family = binomial, data = TrialDF)

 at(indep2) indep1
          0 0.6776
          1 0.1496
```